# How can I get a sticky footer on my WordPress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm trying to get my footer to stick to the bottom of my page. I've followed loads of different tutorials (most of them very similar) on sticky footers, but none of them have worked for me. For some reason the footer sticks to the bottom of the SCREEN instead of the PAGE...

This is the layout of divs in my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;

#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#content {
position: absolute;
padding-bottom: 300px; (same as footer height)
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#00ff0f;
   padding:30px;
}
#main{
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:45px;   /* Height+padding(top and botton) of the footer */
    text-align:justify;
    height:100%; 
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:15px; /* Height of the footer */
    background:#00ff0f;
    padding:10px 0; /*paddingtop+bottom 20*/
}
```

**​HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="main">
        Some Content Here... 
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/7/).

Comment: It should have position:fixed for the floating effect. I modified your fiddle as such http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/7/

Comment: Where ? you did nothing on that fiddle you gave me!

Comment: Apologies, I had clicked run but forgot to click update to get new url. Here is yours with some more content, but same css: http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/11/. The footer is not floating. I change it from position:absolute to position:fixed in the #footer and it is floating here http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/12/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but these days you can use flex-box which allows for variable footer height

```
html, body, #wrapper{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```