# How to structure layout of an HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as how to structure a website. I have a logo at the top, I wanted a navigation bar below that, and finally below that I wanted to have the page's contents. I messed around with it for hours, but I can't seem to get the navigation bar to go below the logo and above the main content. Does anyone have any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

        
<html> 

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>


<style>
      #Slideshow1 img { width:1200px; height:500px }
 </style>


<title> Law Firm </title> <!-- Seriously, don't forget to change that.-->

<div class="heading">
<div id="head">

<div id="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width="1700" height="175">
</div>

<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About us</a>
    <a href="#">Areas of Practice</a>
    <a href="#">Reviews</a>
    <a href="#">I'm running out of ideas</a>
    <a href="#">Boring....</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>





<!-- Include content types, links to external resources, keywords for the search engine, epirations and stuff, and whatever else needs to go here like titles and website icons. -->

</head>

<body> <!-- Obviously, the body starts here. -->

<div class="main">
<div id="content"> <!-- Let's kick it off with some stuff, of course. -->

<!-- Now let's get some java up in here!! -->


    <script>

      var imgArray = new Array();
      imgArray[0] = "images/pic1.png";
      imgArray[1] = "images/pic2.png";

      slideshowFade('Slideshow1','',imgArray,20,5000);
    
    </script>



</div>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look into adding a CSS page. There are plenty of tutorials to get you started.

Comment: You need to post also your `main.css` file so that we can see what you've done so far.

Comment: Please post main.css so people can help...

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you made a JSFiddle of what was going on, but I think I can answer this.

1) You're putting stuff in the head tag. I think you misunderstand what it means. It's not the "heading" of the page, it is ment for information that won't show up on the page itself (like what the page is called, what type of page it is). EVERYTHING (Meaning every div) goes in the `body` tag! The body doesn't mean the body of the website, it means what shows up on the page!

2) I can only guess because you haven't attached the style sheet, but I'm guessing you don't have `clear: both` on navigation, heading, and logo styles.

3) To the same elements I mentioned in #2, you may also want to add `display: block` just in case that isn't already set.

4) If 2 and 3 don't work, try defining heights for all of the elements as well (Sometimes this works for me, depending on what is causing the problem)

1 doesn't fix your problems, but it's right. 2 should fix your problem, but you really need to put `main.css` into your question because I can't know for sure. Also, look into using a `ul` tag for menue. It's worth doing.

Here is a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JqUt/

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your `HTMLK` code in the `head` trag so it's not visible. You should
write everything in between `<body></body>` tags of your page. Just bring your `<div class="heading">` out of the `head` tags and put it inside `body` tag.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361029/how-can-i-get-a-sticky-footer-on-my-wordpress-theme/12361147#12361147) about HTML, if you look at the [fiddle examle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPCWD/7/) then you can understand it a bit. Remember that, every visible elements in a web page is the contents of the `body` tag, which means that, whatever you see in a web page, belongs to `<body>your page content goes here</body>`.

Comment: The browser auto-closes the head so the content is visible.

Comment: @JanDvorak, I didn't get it. The `head` tag is already closed in the example that `OP` provided and he/she put some `html` code inside the `head` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have structural elements (like your `<div>`s) in a `<head>` element.  All structural elements belong in the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little messy code (functional, though) that I make for you:

```
    <body bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100|Lato:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;">
<center>
<div style="color:#c3c3c3;font-size:75px;font-family:Lato;padding-top:25px;font-weight:100;">designing rocks</div>

<div style="text-align:left;width:465px;font-size:20px;font-family:Lato;font-weight:300;padding-top:10px;"><span style="color:#00bbbb;">home</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#c3c3c3;">blah</span>
</center>

<div style="position:absolute;top:165px;left:0px;width:100%;">
<center>
<div style="text-align:left;width:600px;background-color:white;font-family:Lato;font-weight:300;padding:25px;color:gray;">I LOVE content!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can always do embellishments, like a hover effect for the navigation links...
Tell me if it's functional. :)
You could always scrape a little of the ideas for your project.

Oh, and the other answers are correct, the reason why your layout doesn't work could be due to the fact that the page content is in the head. The head is for the title of the page, (title), and scripts you want to load before any other go in the head. The body is the part of the page that's visible to the user.