# CSS html 100 % width height layout

Tags: css, html

I am trying to build a layout that consumes all the space that is visible in browser. I set `html, body height 100%` as was suggested in different SO posts. Following is the markup that I am trying

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.main {
  height: auto;
  padding-right: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.content {    
  height: 2000px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

the content div height cause the whole body to grow and hence the browser's default scroll bars are shown. Though I have set the container div to scroll in order to display the content of content div, still the scroll bars for container div don't show. How can I fix this.

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/eXn8L/)

Comment: [Check this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361029/how-can-i-get-a-sticky-footer-on-my-wordpress-theme/12361147#12361147)

Comment: @SheikhHeera so there is no way of achieving this without using position relative or absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:**

By default the `height` of the div element depends on its content (unlike `width` which takes 100% width of the parent). That's why when you specify the height of inner element as a percentage it won't be accurate if your parent tag has no explicitly defined height (that means height has to be defined up to the very top of the DOM since height is not inheritable).

In your case you need to add  `height: 100%;` or any other height to your `.container` , `.main` and the wrapper `div`

[modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKceP/)

Comment: thanks, setting the height in pixels did work but setting it in %age didn't and thats what I am after. Since setting it in pixels would kill the purpose.

Comment: Try it directly in the browser instead of fiddle

Comment: same result as in my actual code, container div does have height of 100%. The container div is positioned relative though ..

Comment: Sorry, it was working for me because I haven't been using any doctype

Comment: I've change the answer to make it work when doctime is specified