# content div 100% height extends too far

Tags: css, html

I'm having some troubles with getting my content container div to properly extend to the bottom of the page when the content itself does not. if the content is short and does not fill the page the container still extends past the bottom of the page.

Here's the structure:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>



<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="content">


        <div class="post">

        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="centerit">/div>    
</div></body></html>
```

here's the css:

```
body{background:url(bg.jpg);font-family:verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:18px;color:#b3b3b3;height:100%;min-height:100%;}

    a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;outline:none;}

    /* a:hover{color:#289bc6;} */

html { height: 100%; }
    #container{width:1200px;margin:auto;height:100%;position:relative;}

    #logo{font-size:18px;line-height:37px;color:#222;float:left;display:block;clear:both;}

    #nav{margin:auto;background:#000;padding;2px 800px 0px 0px;width:800px;}

    #nav li{display:inline;background:#000;}

    #nav li a{padding:9px 40px 10px 3px;font-weight:normal;color:#fff;background:#000;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:40px;}

#nav li a:hover, #nav li .active, #nav .current_page_item a, #nav li a.current_page_item{background:#fff;color:#000;}

    /* #nav li a:active{background:#289bc6;} */

    .clear{clear:both;}


    .spacer{height:10px;}

    .content{margin:auto;width:800px;height:100%;display:block;clear:both;position:relative;}

.sidebar{margin:auto;padding:10px;width:780px;background:#000;}

.sidebar h3{padding:5px 5px 4px 5px;background:#fff;color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;}

    #categories{border-bottom:1px solid #fff;line-height:21px;}

    #categories li{display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 0;}

    #categories li a{padding:5px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;}

    #categories li a:hover, #categories li b{padding:5px 5px 4px 5px;background:#fff;color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;}

    /* #categories li a:active, #categories li b:hover, #categories li b:active{background:#289bc6;} */



                .post{background:#000;position:relative;clear:both;display:block;clear:both;width:800px;min-height:100%;margin-bottom: 30px;}

    .post .left{width:100px;float:left;margin-top:-10px;height:100%;}

    .post .left h5{font-weight:normal;line-height:72px;font-size:72px;margin-top:10px;}

    .post .left b{font-weight:normal;font-size:25px;line-height:25px;margin-top:-200px;}

    .post .right h2 a{text-transform:uppercase;padding:3px;font-weight:normal;font-size:30px;line-height:32px;}
    .post-390 .right h2 a {display: none;}

    .post .right h2 a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}

    .post .right{width:760px;height:90%;float:left;margin-left:10px;}



    .sidebar ul{line-height:21px;}

    .sidebar ul li{display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 0;}

    .sidebar ul li a{padding:5px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;display:block;}

    .sidebar ul li a:hover{padding:5px;background:#fff;color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;}



    .footerul{line-height:21px;background:#000;}

    .footerul li{display:inline;margin:0 5px 0 0;}

    .footerul li a{padding:5px;color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;display:block;}

    .footerul li a:hover, .footerul li b{padding:5px 5px 4px 5px;background:#fff;color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:normal;}

    /* .footerul li a:active, .footerul li b:hover, .footerul li b:active{background:#289bc6;} */

    /* .footerul li b{border-bottom:1px solid #fff;width:100%;}*/



    #fleft{width:100%;float:left;}

    #fright{width:48%;float:right;}



    #centerit{text-align:center;background:#000;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;position:fixed;bottom:0;width:800px;}



.commentlist li{padding:10px;background:#eee;}

.commentlist li.alt{background:#ddd;}

.alignright {float:right;}

.alignleft {float:left;}
```

Comment: Did you actually miss a `<` in `<div id="centerit">/div>`? Or was that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: What happens is that content div actually gets 100% of html, and because you have elements before content, the page will be 100% plus the height of those elements before and after content. If you could show what design you are trying to achieve, maybe it can be achieved another way

Comment: Don't use a newline for every single new line you make, it looks a little bit neat at first but in the long run It's just a pain in the ass to read through.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry copy and paste mistake with the centerit div.

Comment: It's a wordpress site. I have a header with banner image and nav, then content to display posts, then the footer that is floated to the bottom. I would like the content area (background color) to fill the unused space when the post is short. here's the site: [link](http://caveofswords.com)

Comment: If you are looking for a sticky footer then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361029/how-can-i-get-a-sticky-footer-on-my-wordpress-theme/12361147#12361147) may help you.

Comment: I would like to keep the spacing between the content and the footer constant. so reducing the height % of the content area does not keep that spacing consistant.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust and add this to the mix:

```
html { height: 100%; min-height: 100; /* min-height is for FF */ }
#content { height: -webkit-calc-height(100% - 37px); } /* be sure to add all vendor prefixes, also change 37px to the correct height of elements above the #content */
```