# Keep footer at bottom but not sticky?

Tags: html, css, sticky

My basic layout is simple:

```css
header {
    background: red;
}

main {
    background: aqua;
    font-size: 48px;
}

footer {
    background: grey;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>head</header>
<main>
Curabitur aliquam convallis luctus. Vestibulum dolor turpis, consectetur a placerat eget, pellentesque id eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
</main>
<footer>foot</footer>
```

If I make my footer `position:fixed` it does stay at the bottom of the page, but is a "sticky" footer and covered content when scrolling is needed.

I would like to keep the footer at the bottom, but not be `fixed`.

Is this even possible to do with pure CSS?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ky4Q5/)

Comment: [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361029/how-can-i-get-a-sticky-footer-on-my-wordpress-theme/12361147#12361147) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `position:absolute;`. This Is a CSS property that allows you to control the exact location of any element. For example:

```
<style>
footer {
position:absolute;
top:(numberofuntits)px;
left: (numberofUnits)px;
}

</style>
```

This makes it so no matter what happens to the page, it stays in place, kinda like fixed only more specific. Though I think what you will really need is `position:relative;` So it adjusts the footer relative to other elements on the page. To incorporate that, I've added some other useful styles you might want to consider adding... (found these on www.w3schools.com) I hope this is what you need:

```
 <style>
footer {
    clear: both; //prevents floating elements from right/left of footer
    position: relative; //Positions footer relative to other elements on hte page
    z-index: 1; //z-index positions elements in front or behind eachother, most have a //natual z-index of -1
    height: -3em; //exactly what it says...
    margin-top: 40em; //moves footer to bottom of all elements
}
</style>
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: why 40em? for me it stays way bellow content, when page has to scroll to bottom

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays, flex or grid will do easily:

- grid:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

body>* {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
}


/* does it push footer down  if  too tall  */

main:hover {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

- flex

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body>* {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
}

/* does it push footer down if too tall  */

main:hover {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

---

and for anyone curious or who loved the olden-days `display:table/table-row` *(to use only if your browser doesn't support `flex`and/or `grid` or do not know size of footer while using another method with `float` or `position`)*:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

header > div,
footer > div {
  height: 0; /* will grow like a table*/
}

body>* {
  display: table-row;
}

body>*>div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;
}

/* does it push footer down  if  too tall  */

main:hover > div {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>header</div>
</header>
<main>
  <div>main</div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div>footer</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: holly shananigan this was the only thing it worked for me! tks a bunch

Comment: Just a heads up, the grid version seemed to be broken when I tried it, but flex still works great!

Comment: @AaronTook , there is nothing wrong with the grid version as far i can test . I would even recommend to use the grid version , flex-flow:column has sometimes some bugs , like autoscroll when you set  `column reverse`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, that may simply have been an issue with the HTML I was combining the grid version with. That's probably my mistake, sorry for the confusion, and thanks for this very helpful answer!

Comment: @AaronTook , no troubles , it happens all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way with your code is to move your  within the  tag and remove position: fixed from your CSS code.

```
<header></header>
<main><footer></footer></main>
```

and in your CSS:

```
footer {
    background: grey;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should not put repeated content within `main`. As per W3C, "The main content area of a document includes content that is unique to that document and excludes content that is repeated across a set of documents such as site navigation links, copyright information, site logos and banners and search forms (unless the document or applications main function is that of a search form)."

Answer (score -1):

Easy, change these:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
footer {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    bottom:0;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Here is the [FIDLLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ky4Q5/1/)

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked for

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the footer is hiding some body content, not what the OP wanted.